# Stateful matching of multicast responses in iptables

Tags: multicast, iptables

A central part of my firewall configuration is:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It seems that `RELATED` does not work for multicast responses: when the host sends to a multicast group (in my case a UPnP SSDP discovery, to 239.255.255.250:1900), the corresponding responses from a specific IP address back to the sender's randomly selected port are dropped.

What is the correct way to preserve the `--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED` semantics, but make the response matching work for multicast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem with multicast: netfilter can never be sure whether it's related or not.

The only way you can allow UPnP SSDP will therefore be:

```
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 1900 -j ACCEPT
```

In addition to the existing `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` rule.

Comment: Well, at least in this case it seems it could -- my machine makes the initial request to a multicast address, from an ephemeral port. It thus seems reasonable to permit subsequent messages to this local port as `RELATED`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Christian not really. In netfilter's conntrack, the addresses would be stored as "SRC=<your_IP> DST=239.255.255.250", while the reply is "SRC=<someone's_IP> DST=<your_IP>". Without a helper module, the reply looks unrelated to the original entry. Unfortunately, AFAIK there's no helper module for UPnP.

Comment: @Christian there *is* a way to automatically add UPnP rules into `iptables`, but you'll need an additional piece of software. See this page: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/UPnP (it's for Gentoo, but there should be something similar if you're using other distros).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (and sorry for the delay)! I took a look and as far as I can tell linux-igd is meant for situations where Linux is running on a gateway, so iptables can install rules as needed. For example, the manual says that to start the required daemon you need to provide internal and external interfaces. That does not apply here -- I'd simply like my client to accept the response resulting from the broadcast discovery message it sends.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for SDP Keep alive

Comment: @pepoluan Isn't this dangerous to tell a device to accept all UDP traffic based on source address?  It may be ok for internal net but not for a box in the wild, am I misreading?

Answer (score 13):

With recent Linux kernels (>= 2.6.39) you can use kernel's ipset to workaround limitation of connection tracking. You do not need to write any userspace or kernel helper. For UPnP SSDP it can be written as:

```
$ ipset create upnp hash:ip,port timeout 3
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j SET --add-set upnp src,src --exist
$ iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m set --match-set upnp dst,dst -j ACCEPT
```

First command creates a new ipset called *upnp* which stores tuple (ip address, ip protocol, ip port) and every inserted record expires in 3 seconds.

Second command matches outgoing UPnP SSDP packet (destination is multicast address 239.255.255.250 on udp port 1900) and stores *source ip address* and *source udp port* of packet into ipset *upnp*. First keyword **src** means *source ip address* and second keyword **src** means *source port* as ipset of type *hash:ip,port* always needs such pair. Keyword *--exists* means that for existing record is timer reseted. This stored record is automatically removed in 3 seconds.

Third command matches incoming udp packet and if its destination address and destination port matches some record in ipset *upnp* then this packet is accepted. Syntax **dst,dst** means *destination ip address* and *destination port*.

UPnP clients normally sends udp packet to 239.255.255.250:1090 and wait just 2 seconds for response. So autoexpiration in 3 seconds in ipset is enough.

I have not found on internet any working firewall/iptables configuration for UPnP clients which is not too relax (e.g. accept all incoming UDP packet) or without some userspace tracking or need to patch kernel. Therefore I hope this example helps you.

Comment: This is a great solution, and can be made generic enough for different kinds of multicast services.